# How can undo checked-in files and nuget package updates from Team Foundation Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tfs

I update my mvc project nuget packages and some related files, unfortunately I had checked-in my solution to TFS source control. but I understand this update damaged my project functionality, Now I decide to rollback changes. How I can do it? It is possible to use get specific version by change set to undo nuget updated packages?

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on any folder in the Source Control Explorer and do view history. That should show all changes sets that has happened in that folder tree. From that you can Get the specific version which you want.

**SourceControl ->ViewHistory**

[image]

Comment: Is nuget packages updates undo also?

Comment: yes it will get the exact version which you had

Comment: Should I check make writeable file to checked-in again and undo previous changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you have a few options.

**Rollback a single changeset**

In Source Control Explorer:

- Right click the changeset you wish to rollback
- Choose Rollback entire changeset
- Check in the rollback.

Comment: after checked-in I have not any changes in my project, which option is better to undo?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, this *did not* work for me.  I had a changeset with a combination of changes to NuGet packages and some code changes.  It turns out my changeset was bad; I rolled the changeset back, but the NuGet package changes persisted.  I had to manually revert those.